# How do I specify the type of global variable in sorbet?

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I have a global variable that is defined like this:

```
# -- in rollout_setup.rb
$rollout = Rollout.new(::CachedRolloutStore.new)
T.reveal_type($rollout) # got Rollout

# -- in foo.rb
T.reveal_type($rollout) # got T.untyped
```

Within the file, the type of `$rollout` is inferred correctly. However, it is inferred as `T.untyped` anywhere else that use the variable. I've tried to use `T.let` but it doesn't work.

Comment: "I've tried to use T.let but it doesn't work." What did you try, specifically? Please edit your question to include this code and the output it produced.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added more detail to the post

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; I should have read more carefully.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this locally (Ruby 2.7-dev, Sorbet 0.4.4557). Here's a Gist with all of the files and the `srb tc` output: https://gist.github.com/jrunning/fe882c32580e33c6aac436ec97453ee4 Oddly, passing a non-Rollout to a method expecting a Rollout *does* produce the expected "Expected `Rollout` but…" error but `T.reveal_type` yields `T.untyped` and reassigning `$rollout` to a non-Rollout doesn't produce an error. I have little experience with Sorbet, but this seems like a bug worth [reporting](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/issues/new?labels=bug%2C+unconfirmed&template=bug.md).

Comment: Thanks @JordanRunning! I'll report the bug!

Comment: Issue filed: https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/issues/1465